# String as return type from t() function with i18next

Tags: typescript, i18next, react-i18next

With [i18next v22.0.0](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/releases/tag/v22.0.0) came full type safety for the translation function `t('world.greeting')`, which is great. But since you can use the `t()` function for retrieving objects from nested translations, it may return an object or a string.

I always pass translation keys that result into strings. I mainly use `t()` in a context where it must return a string, so a function like in the following code snippet produces a TypeScript error:

```js
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      world:  {
        withGreeting: 'Hello World',
        withoutGreeting: 'World',
        someNestedProperty: {
          hello: 'Text',
        }
      },
    },
  },
}

// Declare i18next typings: https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript
declare module "i18next" {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: typeof resources["en"];
  }
}


// (...) initialize i18next

const getText = (enabled: boolean): string => {
   if(enabled) {
     // Typescript Error: string | { hello: string } not assignable to type string
     return t('world.withGreeting');  
   }
   return t('world.withoutGreeting');
}
```

Is it possible with some TypeScript magic so that you force `t()` to only return a string?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `translation:` prefix? See https://tsplay.dev/NdrDnW

Comment: Default namespace is `translation`, so it's not required. The code snippet should only be representative of the problem, namely getting `string` as return type from `t()`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. For some reason there isn't any docs about nested objects on their official website. I think there's a missing type def to add but their internal types aren't the most trivial to understand I must say (which is normal given the nature of the task).

Comment: is it possible to create a failing test here: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/test/typescript/custom-types/t.test.ts?
npm run test:typescript:customtypes

Comment: return `${t('world.withGreeting')}`;

Comment: i want to use it like const translatedValue = t(key); is there any way ?